# Is eclipse AutoCompleteField only suggesting entries starting with entered text?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I am using `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.AutoCompleteField` class to suggest my combo box options. But it's not useful, because it only suggests entries matching entered text at the beginning.

JavaCode:

```
   ComboContentAdapter comboAdapter = new ComboContentAdapter();                    
   new  AutoCompleteField(branchCombo,comboAdapter,branchCombo.getItems());
```

Example :

Combo Box Options:

```
['ZMEDIA_TWITTER_MIGRATION_BRANCH','ZMEDIA_TWITTER_HOTFIX_BRANCH','ZMEDIA_FB_BRANCH'].
```

If I type `TWITTER` in combo box it suggests nothing . It looks like the `TWITTER` with startswith match in combobox options .

Is there any option to override this?

Thanks You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, there isn't.

However, this can be achieved by creating your own proposal provider by implementing `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.IContentProposalProvider` and implementing your filtering logic in its' `getProposals(String contents, int position)` method.

Then, just add your proposal provider to a `ContentProposalAdapter` and adapt the combobox, as follows:

```
MyContentProposalProvider provider = new  MyContentProposalProvider(combo.getItems());
ContentProposalAdapter adapter = new ContentProposalAdapter(combo, comboAdapter, provider, null, null);
adapter.setPropagateKeys(true);
adapter.setProposalAcceptanceStyle(ContentProposalAdapter.PROPOSAL_REPLACE);
```

Comment: In case someone is wondering, it looks sufficient to use a "new ComboContentAdapter()" as comboAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as *[tkotisis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618212/tkotisis)* said, you can implement your own IContentProposalProvider, if you want a Provider to give all proposals containing any of the chars that the user have typed you can use this code I came up with.
**NOTE:** The convertion to a char is not neccessary you can use the raw byte too, but if you want to further proccess your Provider it can be easier to use a char!

```
IContentProposalProvider proposalProvider = new IContentProposalProvider() {

            @Override
            public IContentProposal[] getProposals(String contents, int position) {
                String[] props = new String[] { "Test0", "Test1", "Test2",
                        "Test3" }; // This is all your propsals.
                List<IContentProposal> validProposals = new ArrayList<IContentProposal>();
                for (String prop : props) {
                    contents = contents.substring(0, position);
                    for (byte b : contents.getBytes()) {
                        char c = (char) (b & 0xFF);
                        if (prop.indexOf(c) != -1) { // This is where it checks if the proposal contains the chars.
                            validProposals.add(new ContentProposal(prop));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return validProposals.toArray(new IContentProposal[validProposals.size()]);
            }
        };
```